# How to control a capacitance control panel from a Raspberry Pi

Tags: transistors, switches, raspberry-pi, control, capacitance

I have a touch control panel with only one lead going to each "button" on the glass, it is not a full circuit only half of one.
[image]

I have concluded if i ground one of the pins (ex: power), it senses and activates the "button". I need to figure out a way to control this from a raspberry pi. I do believe some sort of transistors would be ideal.[image: picture showing ribbon pins]

I need to know how i can send a signal from the Raspberry Pi's GPIO pins to activate some sort of switch that grounds that lead. basically to trick the control panel into a button click. I have looked into relays but if i can do this without moving parts that would be ideal!

Please help! Thank you all for reading 
-Matt

P.s. i tried this and it did nothing
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The RPi can definitely be used to supply a ground connection! I would recommend looking into the [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) python library and specifically at the 'buzzer' output device.

Comment: Yeah suppling power isn't really the issue, I need to figure out how to put a switch in between the control panel pins and ground, if that connection is always connected it thinks you're holding the button in. I figured i could use a transistor as a switch but my test did not work, im not sure what i did wrong :/